# Displaying a video player to eligible users

Tags: c#, asp.net, video, reference

I posted this on Stack Overflow, but it was suggested that I move it over to Code Review.

I would like some feedback on the way I decided to clean up code from the in a .NET project that had `Page_Load` functions that had been added to over many years to the point that they were a complete mess.

While the code cleanup is the context of the question, this is really a question about if I should or should not be passing by reference to "underscore functions".  Underscore functions are functions that are not meant to be used for encapsulation (although I made all the underscore functions protected) nor "reusability", but instead to wrap code in a human friendly way.  The "clean up" version below is not the final product, but was instead a first stab a cleaning up the code.  The cleaned up code is functioning correctly.

Just to be clear (the code below is a bad example for this), in general I have needed to do mass mutation in the "underscore" functions on other pages. Meaning I have had to change/set the value for multiple variables that are being passed in and then used outside the "underscore" function's scope.

ORIGINAL PAGE_LOAD

```
        public void Page_Load() {
        // Set player to have been initialized
        this.initialized = true;

        if(!this.playerOverride) {
            String vendorValue = Resolver.Resolve("PlayerVender");
            if(vendorValue.Equals("jwplayer")) {
                this.UseVideoRxPlayer = false;
            } else {
                this.UseVideoRxPlayer = true;
            }
        }

        // Get instances for use
        VideoAccess videoAccess = VideoAccess.getInstance();
        LearnerAccess learnerAccess = LearnerAccess.getInstance();

        // Member should be logged in
        if(memberId == null) {
            this.memberId = SessionUtils.getMemberId();
        } else if(SessionUtils.getMemberId() != null && SessionUtils.getMemberId() != memberId) {
            // A member is logged in and it is not the member who was specified on control creation
            throw new Exception("Logged in member is not the member the player is using for reporting data");
        }


        if(memberId != null && videoId != null) {

            List<MemberLicense> licenses = LicenseAccess.getInstance().GetMemberLicenses(Convert.ToInt32(memberId)
                , Convert.ToInt32(videoId));

            MemberLicense license = licenses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.available != null && x.available > 0);
            if (license == null && licenses != null && licenses.Count > 0) {
                license = licenses[0];
            }
            bool hasFreeLicense = false;

            if (license != null){
                licensenum = license.license_id;
                hasFreeLicense = license.available > 0;
                groupId = license.group_id;
            }


            // From here on out we will use memberId and videoId explicitly

            // Get the video with the member's information attached
            FullVideo = videoAccess.GetVideo((int) memberId, (int) videoId);
            if(!(FullVideo.Solution && !SubscriptionModel.HasAnnualSubscription((int) memberId))
                && SubscriptionModel.MemberCanAccessVideo((int) memberId, (int) videoId)) {
                // If this is a solution, the member has access to it. Otherwise, it is a
                // regular video and the member has access to it

                // Set the page title
                Page.Title = FullVideo.ProductName + ": " + FullVideo.Title;

                if(SessionUtils.IsValidSession() && (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || SessionUtils.isCookieUser())) {
                    // If a next video was specified, let's set it for display on video completion
                    if(nextVideo != null) {
                        panels.SpecifiedVideo = (int) nextVideo;
                        panels.NextVideoSpecified = true;
                    }
                    panels.PlayingPlaylistVideo = isPlayingPlaylist;

                    //Get Learner Info
                    Tuple<int?, ContactType?> contactInfo = learnerAccess.GetPrimaryGroupContactInfoForMember((int) memberId);
                    if(contactInfo.Item1 != null) {
                        int PrimaryGroupId = (int) contactInfo.Item1;
                        lp = learnerAccess.GetPrimaryGroupPlanInfo((int) PrimaryGroupId);
                    }

                    if (hasFreeLicense || learnerAccess.IsLearnerMember((int)memberId)) 
                    {
                        initializeVideoHero();
                        if (SeriesId != null && SeriesId != 0)
                        {
                            List<Instructor> surveyLinks = new List<Instructor>();

                            foreach (Instructor i in VideoProduct.Instructors)
                            {
                                surveyLinks.Add(i);
                            }

                            if (surveyLinks.Count > 0)
                            {
                                ratingform1.SurveyLinks = surveyLinks;
                            }
                            initializeRatingForm();
                        }
                        videoFooter.Visible = true;

                        // Member has access to view video
                        if(SessionUtils.getSubDaysLeft() > 0) {
                            panels.Trial = false;
                        } else if(SessionUtils.getHasTrial() != null && (bool) SessionUtils.getHasTrial()) {
                            panels.Trial = true;
                        }
                        panels.ShowPopover(FullVideo);

                        // Display analytics codes for Google Analytics
                        if(showAnalytics) {
                            gaqEventCode.Text = "<script>_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Video', 'Viewed', '"
                                + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(FullVideo.ProductName) + " - "
                                + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(FullVideo.Title) + "']);</script>";
                        }

                        int? lastPosition = videoAccess.GetLastVideoPosition((int)memberId, (int)videoId);
                        if (lastPosition != 0)
                        {
                            lposition = lastPosition;
                        }

                        playerElement.Visible = true;
                        panels.Visible = true;
                    } else if (!hasFreeLicense && license != null) {
                        // Member would have access to this video, but there has been a license issue.
                        // This most likely is indicitive of a legacy account.
                        uclicensesinuse.setShowAddLicensesButtonVisibility(false);
                        videofailure.Visible = true;

                        innerPlayerWrapper.Visible = false;

                        licensesinuse.Visible = true;
                        uclicensesinuse.Visible = true;

                        uclicensesinuse.license = license.license_id;

                        // Store denied license info to database
                        videoAccess.DenyLicense((int)memberId, license.license_id, (int)FullVideo.Product, 
                            (int)FullVideo.Id, (int)RequestedStatus.AllLicensesInUse, SessionUtils.getVisitId(), String.Empty);
                        // Determine if this is an admin. If so, display a button to purchase new licenses
                        if (videoAccess.GetLicenseAdmins((int)license.license_id).Any(m => m.Id == memberId)) {
                            uclicensesinuse.setShowAddLicensesButtonVisibility(true);
                        }

                    } else if (!hasFreeLicense && license == null) {
                        // No longer has an active subscription
                        videofailure.Visible = true;
                        subscriptionexpired.Visible = true;
                        innerPlayerWrapper.Visible = false;
                        if (SessionUtils.IsLearner()) {
                            // This is a learner so they can either renew or start a free trial
                            if (lp.IsFreeTrial) {
                                learnertype.InnerHtml = "free trial";
                                learnerrenewtype.InnerHtml = "Subscribe";
                            } else {
                                learnertype.InnerHtml = "subscription";
                                learnerrenewtype.InnerHtml = "Renew";
                            }
                            learneraccount.Visible = true;
                        } else {
                            // This is a legacy subscription
                            legacyaccount.Visible = true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        videofailure.Visible = true;
                        noaccesspanel.Visible = true;
                        videoerror.Visible = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    // Member is not logged in and should be prompted to start a free trial
                    trialpanel.Visible = true;
                    playerWrapper.Visible = false;
                    videohero.Visible = false;
                }
            } else {

                videofailure.Visible = false;
                noaccesspanel.Visible = true;
                videoerror.Visible = true;
                innerPlayerWrapper.Visible = false;
                videohero.Visible = false;
            }
        } else {
            // Member is not logged in and should be prompted to start a free trial
            trialpanel.Visible = true;
            playerWrapper.Visible = false;
            videohero.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

CLEANED UP PAGE_LOAD VERSION

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if(!initialized) {
            PreparePlayer();
        }
    }

    public void PreparePlayer() {
        // Set player to have been initialized
        this.initialized = true;

        if(!this.playerOverride) {
            String vendorValue = Resolver.Resolve("PlayerVender");
            if(vendorValue.Equals("jwplayer")) {
                this.UseVideoRxPlayer = false;
            } else {
                this.UseVideoRxPlayer = true;
            }
        }

        // Get instances for use
        VideoAccess videoAccess = VideoAccess.getInstance();
        LearnerAccess learnerAccess = LearnerAccess.getInstance();

        // Member should be logged in
        if(memberId == null) {
            this.memberId = SessionUtils.getMemberId();
        } else if(SessionUtils.getMemberId() != null && SessionUtils.getMemberId() != memberId) {
            // A member is logged in and it is not the member who was specified on control creation
            throw new Exception("Logged in member is not the member the player is using for reporting data");
        }


        if(memberId != null && videoId != null) {
            _IfMemberAndVideoExist(ref learnerAccess, ref videoAccess);

        } else {
            // Member is not logged in and should be prompted to start a free trial
            trialpanel.Visible = true;
            playerWrapper.Visible = false;
            videohero.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    protected void _IfMemberAndVideoExist(ref LearnerAccess learnerAccess, ref VideoAccess videoAccess)
    {
        List<MemberLicense> licenses = LicenseAccess.getInstance().GetMemberLicenses(Convert.ToInt32(memberId), Convert.ToInt32(videoId));

        MemberLicense license = licenses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.available != null && x.available > 0);
        if (license == null && licenses != null && licenses.Count > 0)
        {
            license = licenses[0];
        }
        bool hasFreeLicense = false;

        if (license != null)
        {
            licensenum = license.license_id;
            hasFreeLicense = license.available > 0;
            groupId = license.group_id;
        }


        // From here on out we will use memberId and videoId explicitly

        // Get the video with the member's information attached
        FullVideo = videoAccess.GetVideo((int)memberId, (int)videoId);
        if (!(FullVideo.Solution && !SubscriptionModel.HasAnnualSubscription((int)memberId))
            && SubscriptionModel.MemberCanAccessVideo((int)memberId, (int)videoId))
        {

            _IfViewableVideo(ref learnerAccess, ref hasFreeLicense, ref videoAccess, ref license);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!hasFreeLicense && license == null)
            {
                //@TODO this was unreachable due to added check SubscriptionModel.MemberCanAccessVideo((int) memberId, (int) videoId).  Moved this logic here outside of _IfViewableVideo.
                _subscriptionExpired(ref learnerAccess);
            }
            else
            {
                // This is a solution that they don't have access to
                videofailure.Visible = false;
                noaccesspanel.Visible = true;
                videoerror.Visible = true;
                innerPlayerWrapper.Visible = false;
                videohero.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }


    /*
     * 
     * If this is a solution, the member has to have access to it (Annual Sub). Otherwise, it is a regular video and the member has access to it
     */
    protected void _IfViewableVideo(ref LearnerAccess learnerAccess, ref bool hasFreeLicense, ref VideoAccess videoAccess, ref MemberLicense license)
    {

        // Set the page title
        Page.Title = FullVideo.ProductName + ": " + FullVideo.Title;

        if (SessionUtils.IsValidSession() && (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || SessionUtils.isCookieUser()))
        {
            _IfIsValidUser(ref learnerAccess, ref hasFreeLicense, ref videoAccess, ref license);
        }
        else
        {
            // Member is not logged in and should be prompted to start a free trial
            trialpanel.Visible = true;
            playerWrapper.Visible = false;
            videohero.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    protected void _IfIsValidUser(ref LearnerAccess learnerAccess, ref bool hasFreeLicense, ref VideoAccess videoAccess, ref MemberLicense license)
    {
        // If a next video was specified, let's set it for display on video completion
        if (nextVideo != null)
        {
            panels.SpecifiedVideo = (int)nextVideo;
            panels.NextVideoSpecified = true;
        }
        panels.PlayingPlaylistVideo = isPlayingPlaylist;

        //Get Learner Info
        Tuple<int?, ContactType?> contactInfo = learnerAccess.GetPrimaryGroupContactInfoForMember((int)memberId);
        if (contactInfo.Item1 != null)
        {
            int PrimaryGroupId = (int)contactInfo.Item1;
            lp = learnerAccess.GetPrimaryGroupPlanInfo((int)PrimaryGroupId);
        }

        if (hasFreeLicense || learnerAccess.IsLearnerMember((int)memberId))
        {
            _IfLearnerWithAccess(ref videoAccess);
        }
        else if (!hasFreeLicense && license != null)
        {
            _legacyLicenseConflict(ref videoAccess, ref license);
        }
        else if (!hasFreeLicense && license == null)
        {
            //@TODO unreachable due to added check SubscriptionModel.MemberCanAccessVideo((int) memberId, (int) videoId).  This code is still being used.  Moved this logic to outside the IfViewableVideo.
            _subscriptionExpired(ref learnerAccess);
        }
        else
        {
            videofailure.Visible = true;
            noaccesspanel.Visible = true;
            videoerror.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    protected void _IfLearnerWithAccess(ref VideoAccess videoAccess)
    {
        initializeVideoHero();
        _populateInstructorRatings();
        videoFooter.Visible = true;

        // Member has access to view video
        if (SessionUtils.getSubDaysLeft() > 0)
        {
            panels.Trial = false;
        }
        else if (SessionUtils.getHasTrial() != null && (bool)SessionUtils.getHasTrial())
        {
            panels.Trial = true;
        }
        panels.ShowPopover(FullVideo);

        // Display analytics codes for Google Analytics
        if (showAnalytics)
        {
            gaqEventCode.Text = "<script>_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Video', 'Viewed', '"
                + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(FullVideo.ProductName) + " - "
                + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(FullVideo.Title) + "']);</script>";
        }

        int? lastPosition = videoAccess.GetLastVideoPosition((int)memberId, (int)videoId);
        if (lastPosition != 0)
        {
            lposition = lastPosition;
        }

        playerElement.Visible = true;
        panels.Visible = true;
    }

    /*
    * @TODO investigate if the trainer raitings can be removed (except initializeRaitingForm)
    */
    protected void _populateInstructorRatings()
    {
        if (SeriesId != null && SeriesId != 0)
        {
            List<Instructor> surveyLinks = new List<Instructor>();

            foreach (Instructor i in VideoProduct.Instructors)
            {
                surveyLinks.Add(i);
            }

            if (surveyLinks.Count > 0)
            {
                ratingform1.SurveyLinks = surveyLinks;
            }
            initializeRatingForm();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Member would have access to this video, but there has been a license issue
     * This most likely is indicitive of a legacy account.
     * 
     */
    protected void _legacyLicenseConflict(ref VideoAccess videoAccess, ref MemberLicense license)
    {
        uclicensesinuse.setShowAddLicensesButtonVisibility(false);
        videofailure.Visible = true;

        innerPlayerWrapper.Visible = false;

        licensesinuse.Visible = true;
        uclicensesinuse.Visible = true;

        uclicensesinuse.license = license.license_id;

        // Store denied license info to database
        videoAccess.DenyLicense((int)memberId, license.license_id, (int)FullVideo.Product,
            (int)FullVideo.Id, (int)RequestedStatus.AllLicensesInUse, SessionUtils.getVisitId(), String.Empty);
        // Determine if this is an admin. If so, display a button to purchase new licenses
        if (videoAccess.GetLicenseAdmins((int)license.license_id).Any(m => m.Id == memberId))
        {
            uclicensesinuse.setShowAddLicensesButtonVisibility(true);
        }

    }

    /*
     * Member no longer has an active subscription.
     * 
     * 
     */
    protected void _subscriptionExpired(ref LearnerAccess learnerAccess)
    {

        //Get Learner Info
        Tuple<int?, ContactType?> contactInfo = learnerAccess.GetPrimaryGroupContactInfoForMember((int)memberId);
        if (contactInfo.Item1 != null)
        {
            int PrimaryGroupId = (int)contactInfo.Item1;
            lp = learnerAccess.GetPrimaryGroupPlanInfo((int)PrimaryGroupId);
        }

        // No longer has an active subscription
        videofailure.Visible = true;
        subscriptionexpired.Visible = true;
        innerPlayerWrapper.Visible = false;
        if (SessionUtils.IsLearner())
        {
            // This is a learner so they can either renew or start a free trial
            if (lp.IsFreeTrial)
            {
                learnertype.InnerHtml = "free trial";
                learnerrenewtype.InnerHtml = "Subscribe";
            }
            else
            {
                learnertype.InnerHtml = "subscription";
                learnerrenewtype.InnerHtml = "Renew";
            }
            learneraccount.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // This is a legacy subscription
            legacyaccount.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I suggest you only include the post-cleanup code; reviewers won't make a *diff* of the two and review your *changes* - they'll more likely tell you what you've missed and what's left to do with the last version of the code ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you call "underscore functions" are actually the result of a few principles including *separation of concerns*, *single responsibility* and sure, there is some *encapsulation* involved as well but that's not really prevalent.

So in that regard: it's definitely a good thing that you are splitting this in multiple methods because it really makes it easier to follow the flow of your application.

That being said, let's start critiquing!

---

You're setting `initialized` to `true` before you've even started initializing anything. I would do this at the very end to indicate that everything is finished and succesful (I don't assume you want to mark things initialized when in reality the program crashed).

---

I'm noticing explicit `this` prefixes. Typically I only do this when I have to remove ambiguity between two variables with the same name in the same scope (or when it is required to compile, of course). Adding this clutters the code a little bit more.

---

I prefer to define (almost) all of my variables as `var` and when it's a string, I use the lowercase `string` instead of `String`. It just feels nicer and in the case of `var`: keeps the focus on what's important.

---

C# is awesome! For strings, we can just use `==` instead of `.Equals`.

I find `vendorValue == "jwplayer"` cleaner than `vendorValue.Equals("jwplayer")`.

---

Boolean assignments like this:

```
if(vendorValue.Equals("jwplayer")) {
    this.UseVideoRxPlayer = false;
} else {
    this.UseVideoRxPlayer = true;
}
```

can be combined to this:

```
UseVideoRxPlayer = vendorValue != "jwplayer";
```

---

I'd avoid throwing `Exception` because it will make it impossible later on to distinguish between an exception you've thrown and an unknown exception caused by code, should you wrap all this around a general `catch(Exception)` to make sure nothing slips through the cracks.

Often this is worked around by creating a custom `MyApplicationException` class and throwing your selfdefined errors with that.

---

Keep naming in mind: `protected` members are UpperCamelCase. Underscores are only considered best practice as `private` fields.

---

In `_IfMemberAndVideoExist` you use two variables `memberId` and `videoId` which you convert to integers. This implies that these Ids are stored as a type they shouldn't be outside of your method.

This poses 2 issues:

1. You'll have to convert it to the appropriate type everywhere it will be used
2. You can get exceptions if the fields contain inappropriate values

Both issues can be solved by storing the fields in the correct datatype.

---

```
licenses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.available != null && x.available > 0);
```

This line seems to indicate you have a `Nullable<int>` property called `available`.

First of all: the naming convention for properties is that they're UpperCamelCase.
Secondly: `available` in itself doesn't tell me what it is (I know it has something to do with a license, but what exactly..)

---

I prefer `licenses.Any()` over `licenses.Count > 0`

---

Take a closer look at this code snippet:

```
MemberLicense license = licenses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.available != null && x.available > 0);
if (license == null && licenses != null && licenses.Count > 0)
{
    license = licenses[0];
}
bool hasFreeLicense = false;

if (license != null)
{
    licensenum = license.license_id;
    hasFreeLicense = license.available > 0;
    groupId = license.group_id;
}
```

As far as I can tell from first sight: if you have a situation where `license` is initially `null` and `licenses` has items **but** the first item in that list (aka: index `0`) is `null` then `licensenum`, `hasFreeLicense` and `groupId` will not be set.

This might not have been a problem but `license` is never reassigned so it will remain `null`. This *will* crash your program if a flow is followed where eventually `_legacyLicenseConflict` will be called: there the `license.license_id` field is used. This will result in a `NullReferenceException`.

---

Your code is cluttered with casts of `memberId` and `videoId` to integers. I would **strongly** encourage you to change the backing field. If that is not possible then  at least use a temporary variable in method scope.

---

`FullVideo.Solution` is not an appropriate boolean naming. It should `IsSolution`, `HasSolution` or something similar which indicates what exactly that solution means.

---

`nextVideo` also seems to be a private field which is the wrong datatype.

---

You are now manually setting `NextVideoSpecified` to true, although this is actually a computed value based on whether or not `SpecifiedVideo` is `null` or not.

It isn't unthinkable that someone might forget to do this someday so I would make this implicit:

```
public bool IsNextVideoSpecified { get { return SpecifiedVideo != null; } }
```

---

```
int PrimaryGroupId = (int)contactInfo.Item1;
lp = learnerAccess.GetPrimaryGroupPlanInfo((int)PrimaryGroupId);
```

`PrimaryGroupId` is already an integer, calm down!

---

```
initializeVideoHero()
```

should be

```
InitializeVideoHero()
```

Methods are UpperCamelCase.

---

I would rename `getSubDaysLeft()` to `GetSubscriptionDaysLeft()`. There is no reason to sacrifice readability to save 10 pixels.

---

```
if (SessionUtils.getSubDaysLeft() > 0)
{
    panels.Trial = false;
}
else if (SessionUtils.getHasTrial() != null && (bool)SessionUtils.getHasTrial())
{
    panels.Trial = true;
}
```

This implies that if neither of the two conditions are true, `panels.Trial` will have its current value. I can't know from the code whether that is intended but if you never set `Trial` elsewhere, this means it will have the default value of `false`. In that case I would incorporate this in your code by making it explicit:

```
panels.Trial = SessionUtils.getHasTrial() != null && (bool)SessionUtils.getHasTrial()
```

Once more: `getHasTrial()` shouldn't have to be casted.

---

`lposition` is not a good name. I assume it means `lastPosition` but that should be written out entirely and follow naming conventions.

---

You can shorten this:

```
List<Instructor> surveyLinks = new List<Instructor>();

foreach (Instructor i in VideoProduct.Instructors)
{
    surveyLinks.Add(i);
}
```

to this:

```
List<Instructor> surveyLinks = new List<Instructor>();
surveyLinks.AddRange(VideoProduct.Instructors);
```

or even

```
List<Instructor> surveyLinks = new List<Instructor>(VideoProduct.Instructors);
```

---

`uclicensesinuse` and all other variables in this neighbourhood should be using lowerCamelCase styling.

---

Here too: I prefer `string.Empty` over `String.Empty`. Takes away some of the black color in your IDE and it feels slimmer. All the cool kids use it.

---

## Conclusion

Overall the code is very well written and easy to follow. Some styling remarks that can be solved by following the conventions and some code that can be written less verbose but I couldn't find anything that struck me as potentially performance hindering so you're good on that aspect.

It's fine to use the `ref` parameters, nothing wrong with it. The naming of your methods are all in the form of `[Condition]` whereas convention dictates `[Action]`. This results in "*IfSubscriptionExpired*" vs "*DisplayRenewSubscriptionDialog*".

I can see where you're coming from with the `[Condition]` scheme since you are basically building a flowchart so I would be okay with it if it makes things easier in your case.

Comment: `List<T>.Count` isn't too bad - it's `IEnumerable<T>.Count()` that's much better off as `IEnumerable<T>.Any()`, to avoid iterating *the entire* collection just to see if there's 1 item. +1 anyway, great, great review as always :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to really look at the code!  Most of it is code that was written before me, but I really appreciate your comments.  I actually plan on implementing some of your suggestions.

I appricate the conclusion as well, because the real concern I have here is another developer coming along and thinking I was crazy and ruining performance.  I've gone a little overboard with the ALWAYS passing by reference into these "underscore" function.

If I mark this as an answer will there still be some discussion about it?  I would like to see if there are any detractors.

Comment: Great review, but I'd use "PascalCase" instead of "UpperCamelCase" and simply "CamelCase" instead of "lowerCamelCase".